# Not able to call shell script from procedure using java source

Tags: java, sql, oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I was trying to execute shell script located on DB environment by executing a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RUNSS
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Command.run()';
```

That runs a java source which calls the shell script using `ProcessBuilder` class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Command {
public static void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String dir="/u01/app/temp";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("caller.sh");
    pb.directory(new File(dir));
    Process pr = pb.start();    
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("ok!");

    in.close();
}

}
```

But when I execute the procedure as:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000;
EXEC DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(10000);
EXECUTE RUNSS;
```

It gives error as:

```
execute runss
Error report -
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "caller.sh" (in directory "/u01/app/temp"): caller.sh not found (Note that lookup with PATH isn't done due to the oracle executable being setuid.)
ORA-06512: at "UCA.RUNSS", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
Exception in thread "Root Thread" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "caller.sh" (in directory "/u01/app/temp"): caller.sh not found (Note that lookup with PATH isn't done due to the oracle executable being setuid.)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:495)
    at Command.run(COMMAND:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: caller.sh not found (Note that lookup with PATH isn't done due to the oracle executable being setuid.)
    at java.lang.OracleProcess.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.OracleProcess.construct(OracleProcess.java:112)
    at java.lang.OracleProcess.<init>(OracleProcess.java:42)
    at java.lang.OracleProcess.start(OracleProcess.java:383)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:488)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: `Note that lookup with PATH isn't done due to the oracle executable being setuid.` Did you grant any java permission. `select * from user_JAVA_POLICY where type_name in ('java.io.FilePermission','java.lang.RuntimePermission');`

Comment: Yes i have the following permissions on user `java.io.FilePermission on u01/app/temp/*` and `java.lang.RuntimePermission`

Comment: And when I change the java source to as `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");` it returns the list of all files in that directory but it doesn't work for `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("caller.sh");`

Comment: 1) Option in DB. add all premission to java.io.FilePermission on u01/app/temp/* (read ,write, execute, delete)

2) Option in Linux change [setuid](http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/).

Comment: Gave the permissions as `java.io.FilePermission` on `u01/app/temp/*` to `(read ,write, execute, delete)` but still getting the same error